# Solving a poset for less than equal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I don't completely understand posets yet, so I'm confused on how to do this particular problem. Here is the question:

Let S be the set of all real numbers.  Prove that the less than or equal to relation ($\leqslant$) taken with S forms a poset.

How do you solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple.

(1) State what the definition of a poset is.

(2) Show that $(S,\leq)$ satisfies this definition.

I'm not being facetious. This is what you must do.